# how to rebuilt widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am developing e-commerce app in flutter, in Home Screen I have a general page but there is categories at it is here :

[Home Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Jyrx.png)

So when I click each category the whole screen should re build and change to categories items widget.

I have a method each time user click one of the categories the screen will re built:

```
void _switchToCategories(String categoryValue) {
    setState(() {
      _categoryScreen = true;
      category = categoryValue;
    });
  }
```

so I have a condition when the screen is build

```
(_categoryScreen)?
            ProdcutsPerCategory(category: category): 
            other column
```

but there is a problem, the ProdcutsPerCategory widget only build once with the first category being selected,

that means even if I select another category the widget did not re create and give me that category products.
and I am using setState() also.

any idea?

Comment: Can you post more code? It's not enough to see what is going on

Comment: the idea is simple, flutter did not re-built the widget because I think that is is the same as the old one, even when I am changing the argument

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the exact same problem and I did a little work around,
but first let me explain what I think that's happening, you are using the same widget `ProdcutsPerCategory` and changing the passed argument so dart renders the same old object marking it the same,
my work around was that I created a widget for every type of category and putting it in list

```
List<Widgets> listOfCatigory = [ProdcutsPerCategory(cat1),ProdcutsPerCategory(cat3),ProdcutsPerCategory(cat3)]
```

so the sample code would be something like this

```
// default widget
var widget catWidget = listOfCatigory[0];
void _switchToCategories(int selectedIndex) {
    setState(() {
      _categoryScreen = true;
      catWidget = listOfCatigory[selectedIndex];
    });
  }
```

and render it like this

```
(_categoryScreen)?
            catWidget: 
            other column
```

Comment: I did the exact what you did still don't re built, I don't know what is the issue

Comment: I created a list of widgets each one for each category, but still flutter read it as one widget a did not re-built it

Comment: try providing a unique key, that should work

Comment: that work, thank you so much. You saved hours of my live in searching thank you a lot

Comment: that made me happy, glad i could help

Answer (score 0):

Maybe in your `ProdcutsPerCategory` widget, you use the category in the initState (which can only happen once) ... With more code, we could help you more easily!